# Testing HTML parser

Tags: ruby, testing, nokogiri, vcr

I am trying to implement some tests for HTML parser written on ruby and using Nokogiri for parsing, it gets it's response from some http request.

Currently the test uses a fixture (html file that is saved). but the problem is that from time to time the real response changes (ids or classes of elements change) so that the parser won't parse it correctly. but the test still passes because it uses the static fixture.

Could you recommend an approach for dealing with such situations?

Comment: What exactly are you testing? What does your test look like? What is the purpose of the testing, i.e. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I see three possible ways to achieve this:

1. You create a rake task which updates the HTML file by downloading the new version from the Internet. When you want to deal with content, simply run the rake task and then run your tests.
2. You make your tests live. It means that instead of parsing your local file during your tests, you download the latest version and run your test with it.
3. It's a mix between 1 and 2. When you start your tests, you can set an `ENV` parameter such as `LIVE=true`. If `LIVE` is `true`, you're are going to download the latest version of your content from the Internet and save it locally. Then you'll run your tests by using the downloaded content.
   If you run your tests with `LIVE=false`, you will not download the content from the Internet and simply use your downloaded content.

Make sense?

Hope it helps!

Comment: `LIVE=!true` should probably be `LIVE=false`.

Comment: Yep, in fact every values different from true including false and nil. I've updated my answer :-)